# Is there a force that moves a magnet in a static field perpendicular to its direction of motion?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

I’m wondering if any configuration of magnets or wires will cause a magnet or magnetizable material moving in proximity to be directed perpendicular to its current direction of motion.

I spent some time googling around, and stumbled on things like the Lorentz force, but couldn’t find anything that meets the “cause to move perpendicular to direction of motion” requirement. Not the easiest thing to find the right wording to research.

Comment: Do you ask if there is a force perpendicular to motion? If that is the question then yes Lorentz force would be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

An electric charge moving in a magnetic field is accelerated perpendicularly to both its velocity and the direction of the magnetic field (as the cross product of velocity and magnetic field).

The force of the magnet on the charge

$F_{BE} = Q \vec v \times \vec B$

By extension, a magnet moving in an electric field is likewise accelerated, although the dipole nature of the magnet can make it awkward to calculate the evolution over time. But in principle, just add a negative sign to the above equation and you have the force of the charge on the magnet.

$F_{EB} = -Q \vec v \times \vec B$

A dipole in a magnetic field is linearly accelerated towards the gradient of the field and rotationally accelerated towards the direction of the field vector. You could set that up so that the magnet happened to always be accelerated perpendicularly to its velocity, but it will be unstable. Any deviation in initial conditions will cause the system to evolve such that acceleration is increasingly less perpendicular to velocity.

---

Edit for clarity:

The reason why the case of the magnet as the free body is problematic even though the case of the charge as the free body is easy:

It is the relative velocity of the charge to the magnetic field that matters, not the relative velocity of the charge to the source of the magnetic field. Unlike an electric field, which (for a point charge) doesn't change if the point charge is rotated, the magnetic field, being produced by a dipole, is completely sensitive to the rotation of a magnet. The result is that the velocity of the magnetic field at the charge is

$\vec v = \vec v_{charge-relative-to-magnet} + \vec \omega \times \vec r$

where $\vec r$ is the displacement from the magnet to the charge and $\vec \omega$ is the rotational velocity of the magnet as measured from the charge's reference frame. If we can take the magnet's reference frame and treat the charge as the free body (either we make the magnet very heavy and the charge very light so that inertia lets us treat it as stationary, or we physically anchor it so that it can't rotate), then $\vec \omega = 0$ and the problem goes away.